# What is the appropriate torque for a single bolt saddle clamp

Tags: saddle, clamp

I had to adjust my saddle position and was unsure how tight the saddle clamp should be attached to the tube. Some numbers (22-24?) are engraved on the clamp (first image), but I'm not sure if they indicate the torque. I first tightened the screw with 19 Nm, then loosened it and only used 14 Nm. I now know that I would only have to tighten it enough to stop the saddle from moving. Have I already tightened the screw with 19 Nm too much and should it be replaced to be on the safe side? I didn't notice any lengthening of the screw when screwing it in. The specified strength is 10.9. Such a long post for such a small part... Btw similar clamps are sold with specification of 22 Nm (second image), which seems pretty high to me.

[image: clamp with engraved torque specs?]

[image: similar type saddle clamp]

Comment: "should it be replaced" Interesting question from a material point of view (not just wrt cycling): Is it possible to overtorque a bolt yet not strip the threads?

Comment: You can crank that as hard as you like. 22Nm is absolutely reasonable for that size bolt, and quite common for that style clamp.

Comment: Chainset bolts rated 10.9 etc are also marked 35-45Nm, for reference.

Comment: @Noise the diameter of the bolt and the thread pitch (fine thread vs. coarse thread) are major factors when relating a bolt material/hardness/strength rating (the 10.9 rating), so you cannot directly compare a torque capacity for a similar rated fastener unless these factors are also in common with the items being compared.

Comment: I was indeed aware @TedHohl ! I believe that in this particular case, the thread pitch and diameter is identical so it's a good comparison.

Comment: @Noise - thanks for clarifying that.  With that similarity in diameter and pitch your comparison is solid!!

Comment: What confuses me a little is that according to this chart: https://www.anzugsmoment.de/metric-threads/metric-thread-bolt-torque-chart/ for a M7 screw (which should be the size of the saddle clamp bolt) the recommended torque is 19 Nm which is quite less than the specification in my second image. Maybe it's because of the specific screw type?

Comment: I'd say that it was a bit loose when disassembling it due to different materials in bolt (steel) and upper threaded part (aluminium). As long as the threaded part has it's threads intact, just reinstall it. If you are really concerned, use a drop of lower grade (like Loctite 222 or 243) thread-locking fluid.